# Error with Spring deprecation in future releases of Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, spring, xcode

I am using Spring in a project I am working on for a open source radio app.

The code is:

```
@IBInspectable var firstSelectedImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        if let image = firstSelectedImage {
            var tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]!
            tabBarItems?[0].selectedImage = image.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I have come across is the line:

```
var tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]!
```

Xcode throws the error:

> Using '!' here is deprecated and will be removed in a future release<

What do I need to use, I have tried without, I have tried using ? but I keep getting errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is spring and what does it have to do with the code you posted and the error? This looks like vanilla UIKit APIs.

Comment: Simply drop the `as [UITabBarItem]!`. Why are you needlessly casting the value?

Comment: Also, why does your code blindly assume there is at least one item? Your code will crash if there are no items.

Comment: This is spring https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/tree/master/Spring I am just trying to get the code I have to work without any depreciations. I am using Swift Radio Pro which hasn't been updated in several years, hence trying to get something that works on new iOS. I will try what you have suggested tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: But my point is that your question has nothing to do with spring. There's no need to mention it in your question at all.

Comment: This is the reason why I only come onto this site if I really need to. Normally, if I am asked for help, I want to know if you are using open source scripting as it helps provide a valid answer. Spring is open source, I am trying to work with spring. I thought it would be helpful if you knew the code was on the off chance anyone else has come across the same issue.

Comment: If you take the

    [UITabBarItem]!

out of the line, you get a load or critical errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution it's pretty simple:
1. Forced unwrapping or forced up and downcasting is really really unsafe, probably this is the reason Apple is removing it.

```
var tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]!
```

change it for:

```
var tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]?
```

but tabBarItems can be nil, so I recommend a guard or something like that.

```
guard var tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]? else { return }
```

example code:

```
class C1 {

}

class C2: C1 {

}

let cc2 = C2()

var firstSelectedImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        if let image = firstSelectedImage {
            guard var tabBarItems = cc2 as C1? else {return}
            print(tabBarItems)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the cast on `var tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]?` since `self.tabBar.items` is already declared as `[UITabBarItem]?`.

Comment: @rmaddy I forget to check that, we were drowning in a glass of water.

Comment: Brilliant! I needed nine of these instances, just as it is in the original spring code.

This is what I ended up doing:

@IBInspectable var normalTint: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = normalTint
            UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: normalTint], for: UIControl.State())
        }
    }

Thank you very much! It's a shame that others seem to pick up on small things that have nothing to do with them instead of just trying to help.